# C# Reading a text file that also contains XML

Tags: c#, regex, xml

I'm reading in a text file and outputting the content. Within the text file there are some random lines of XML. While I can read in and display the text from the text file, there is a problem in that none of the xml is read in or displayed.
Here is my code:

This is the path to the text file

```
    string strFilePath = @"C:\Users\Desktop\docs\textFile1.txt";
```

This is the RegEx to separate out the text file based on date and time so I can display contents in order of date and time

```
    string strRegXPattern = @"(?<date>(?<day>\d{1,2})-(?<month>\d{1,2})-(?<year>(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))\s(?<time>(?<hour>\d{2}):(?<minutes>\d{2}):(?<seconds>\d{2})(?<milli>\.?\d{0,3}))):\s(?<textEntry>.*)";
```

Here I am adding the strFilePath and strRegXPattern to a method ReadFileText() to read the text file. The contents are added to a list of lines.

```
    lstLines.AddRange(base.ReadFileText(strFilePath, strRegXPattern));
```

All of this works fine for the text within the text file. I then merge all the lines based on date and time and display in order. Everything works and displays except for the few random lines of XML here and there within the text file.

Sample content of a text file showing text and XML:

```
    13-01-2015 12:33:39: Some text here.....
    13-01-2015 12:33:41: Some text here.....
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <Request >
    <RequestType>1</RequestType>
    <TsTxnId>123456</TsTxnId>
    </Request>
    13-01-2015 12:34:16: Some text here.....
    13-01-2015 12:34:16: Some text here.....
```

I want to read in and output it so it looks the same, and in order. What is outputting now though is the following:

```
    13-01-2015 12:33:39: Some text here.....
    13-01-2015 12:33:41: Some text here.....
    13-01-2015 12:34:16: Some text here.....
    13-01-2015 12:34:16: Some text here.....
```

None of the XML outputs?

My question is: Can anyone tell me how I include the XML so it can be read in and displayed along with the other lines of standard text within the text file? Currently it is not being read in or displayed at all. 
Thank you.

Comment: Could you please provide the input and desired output? It is impossible to help you without those details.

Comment: Hi @stribizhev. I have added that now.

Comment: There must be something strange in your `ReadFileText` routine. For the usual read/write routines xml is just plain text.

Comment: Also, I am reading in many files at a time, not just one. I am reading them all in, merging them and outputting to one larger file in order of date and time. It's all working fine apart from the XML not appearing.

Comment: Break this down to one line containig xml. Use the debugger, inspect variable contents. Which line of your code goes wrong?

Comment: Yes @DrKoch. I thought it would just read the XML like the rest of the text and display it but it just doesn't appear. No errors are thrown. I can't figure it out?

Comment: @NepSyn14: Do you want to just match `<...>` constructs by the regex as well? Have a look at http://goo.gl/JJfjGH. Does it do what you need? Mind that this will overfire, since XML is split across several lines, and you are reading them line by line.

Comment: Hi @stribizhev. This helps.I thought I could just include the <xml....> as part of the (?<textEntry>.*) on the previous line, but it doesn't read it in this way. I will have to allow for it to be included when it randomly appears within the text as a separate <textEntry>. It's a bit awkward for outputting as I think I will have to concatenate the two <textEntry> parts together to be output together following the same date and time. That's something else for me to go and figure out now. You helped though. At lest it is reading in the XML now. That's progress! Thanks.

Comment: Shall I post it as an answer then?

Comment: Hi @stribizhev. Thank you, you helped me but @ karthik figured out my regex difficulty. If I could give you both votes I would. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, so no point, if you have a working solution. Good luck with programming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
string strRegXPattern = @"(?<date>(?<day>\d{1,2})-(?<month>\d{1,2})-(?<year>(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))\s(?<time>(?<hour>\d{2}):(?<minutes>\d{2}):(?<seconds>\d{2})(?<milli>\.?\d{0,3}))):\s(?<textEntry>[\s\S]*?)(?=(?:\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-(?:\d{4}|\d{2})\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.?\d{0,3})|$)";
```

I made your regex to accept multiple lines adding `[\s\S]`.. so that it will capture text in other lines also.. and made it non greedy `?` so that it wont capture next pattern.

See [DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3Cdate%3E(%3F%3Cday%3E%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D)-(%3F%3Cmonth%3E%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D)-(%3F%3Cyear%3E(%3F%3A%5Cd%7B4%7D%7C%5Cd%7B2%7D))%5Cs(%3F%3Ctime%3E(%3F%3Chour%3E%5Cd%7B2%7D)%3A(%3F%3Cminutes%3E%5Cd%7B2%7D)%3A(%3F%3Cseconds%3E%5Cd%7B2%7D)(%3F%3Cmilli%3E%5C.%3F%5Cd%7B0%2C3%7D)))%3A%5Cs(%3F%3CtextEntry%3E%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D*%3F)(%3F%3D(%3F%3A%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D-%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D-(%3F%3A%5Cd%7B4%7D%7C%5Cd%7B2%7D)%5Cs%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D%5C.%3F%5Cd%7B0%2C3%7D)%7C%24)&i=13-01-2015%2012%3A33%3A39%3A%20Some%20text%20here.....%0D%0A%20%20%20%2013-01-2015%2012%3A33%3A41%3A%20Some%20text%20here.....%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%20standalone%3D%22yes%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRequest%20%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRequestType%3E1%3C%2FRequestType%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CTsTxnId%3E123456%3C%2FTsTxnId%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRequest%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%2013-01-2015%2012%3A34%3A16%3A%20Some%20text%20here.....%0D%0A%20%20%20%2013-01-2015%2012%3A34%3A16%3A%20Some%20text%20here.....)

Comment: Hi @karthik manchala. Thank you. I tried this but it doesn't work unfortunately. Using this RegEx the text entry doesn't display at all.